# Cannot install onboard

Tags: apt, 20.04, python3

I want to install onboard on my Ubuntu 20.04. It is giving me this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 onboard : Depends: python3 (< 3.8) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
           Recommends: gir1.2-ayatanaappindicator3-0.1 but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: gir1.2-atspi-2.0 but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: onboard-data (>= 1.4.1-4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have 3 Python versions installed (3.8.10 <- preinstalled, 3.10.4 and 3.11.0a7). `apt` is only detecting Python 3.8. Fix possible?

Edit: I am sure my system does not contain broken packages (when I install other stuff the error does not appear). So I think it is related to the installation.

Comment: Hello. It is working the way it should Python 3.8 is the version for this version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Does that mean i simply CANNOT install the package in any ways? If not, any solution?

Comment: Did not say that and I do not know. I am just telling you that apt-get update is for the version your Ubuntu needs. How did you install the other 2 version of Python?

Comment: Adding the deadsnakes ppa and then `apt install python3.10 python3.11`

Comment: Remove the PPA from the sources list and it will stop trying to update the python that the PPA  points to.

Comment: If you need other versions of Python a much safer and better way is in a VM.